# Stop ngTable getData for ngTableDynamic to fetch data when sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ngtable

The ngTable document does not provide complete information and sample codes and hard to follow. I managed to make bellow code to fetch and display a table from server dynamically. But when I click the table header to sort, the getData (and so the $http) is triggered again, and the result is that after click, the column is not sorted, but the displayed data doubled itself horizontally (say, when open the page, the displayed columns are [id, name], after the click on a column of the table header, it becomes [id, name, id, name]).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ng-table/ng-table.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-table/ng-table.min.css" />
  <script>
    (function () {
      'use strict';
      let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);
      app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$http', 'NgTableParams', function ($http, NgTableParams) {
        let ctrl = this;
        ctrl.cols = [];
        ctrl.rows = [];
        ctrl.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
          getData: function (params) {
            ctrl.xhr = $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/ng-table-demo/test_data',
            }).then(function (rsp) {
              let cols = Object.keys(rsp.data[0]);
              for(let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                ctrl.cols.push({field: cols[i], title: cols[i], sortable: cols[i], show: true});
              }
              ctrl.rows = rsp.data;
              return ctrl.rows;
            }, function (rsp) {
              console.log('http failed.');
            });
            return ctrl.xhr;
          }});
        }]);
      })();

    (function () {
      "use strict";
      angular.module("myApp").run(configureDefaults);
      configureDefaults.$inject = ["ngTableDefaults"];
      function configureDefaults(ngTableDefaults) {
        ngTableDefaults.params.count = 5;
        ngTableDefaults.settings.counts = [];
      }})();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>ng-table-demo</h2>
    <table ng-table-dynamic="ctrl.tableParams with ctrl.cols" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{row[col.field]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to surround the ctrl.xhr block with bellow, then it stops to duplicate but the sort does not happen anyway.

```
if(ctrl.xhr === undefined) {
  ctrl.xhr = $http...;
}
return ctrl.xhr;
```

What mistake(s) I made?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is abandon of `getData` and set the `dataset` on xhr succeeded. bellow code worked.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);
  app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$http', 'NgTableParams', function ($http, NgTableParams) {
    let ctrl = this;
    ctrl.cols = [];
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/ng-table-demo/test_data',
    }).then(function (rsp) {
      let cols = Object.keys(rsp.data[0]);
      for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        ctrl.cols.push({
          field: cols[i],
          title: cols[i],
          sortable: cols[i],
          show: true
        });
      }
      ctrl.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        dataset: rsp.data
      });
    }, function (rsp) {
      console.log('http failed.');
    });
  }]);
})();
```

Still, I don't know how `getData` works.